# How can we test android app in all devices?

Tags: android

In real world , no can test his App in all android devices available in market.

Is there a tool to test my app to check performance and etc.

Or, What is the best way of testing android apps.

**Update:**
best way is to create emulators and test it. But we don't know all devices with models.

Can you share your valuable thoughts. Thank you

Comment: You can test it on an emulator, for a specific model

Comment: Very simply, I set up different emulators, with different sizes and different OS versions. I also do some tests on some physical devices I have.

Comment: @Gautham how do you know that specific models in market. There are n number of models in market.

Comment: Rather than aiming to test it on *all* models in the market, you should try to test it on an array of models which encompasses as many **phone brands** and as many **Android OS versions** as possible :)

Comment: I am already doing in as many phone brands and Android OS versions. But Is there any other way to test for devices which we don't know

Comment: Why is it down voted. See below possibility of answers.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to test for specific devices, Samsung has a [remote test lab](http://developer.samsung.com/remotetestlab/rtlDeviceList.action), this way you can test real devices virtually and a large variety of devices.

Or else you can go for

http://www.keynotedeviceanywhere.com/mobile-testing.html
http://www.perfectomobile.com/
https://www.lesspainful.com/

Got this answer from Other SO, Just combined some answer.

Comment: Thank for your answer and let me check your links

Comment: No problem, Take your time and check the links, if it is useful for you then kindly accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to answer your question from an automation point of view -

There are some really cool tools in the market to help you perform automated testing for Android, iOS & Windows phones.

My personal favorite of them all will be [SeeTest](http://experitest.com/) (by Experitest). There are others like [FoneMonkey](http://www.cloudmonkeymobile.com/fonemonkey-ios), [MonkeyRunner](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html), [Meux-Test](http://www.jamosolutions.com/), [Robotium](https://code.google.com/p/robotium/) etc.

These tools are very advanced - they provide good reports, have image recognition & cross device support. Suppose you write a automation code for Android App, you can find ways to reuse those for iOS. This will save a lot of your time in SDLC.

All these tools have a CLOUD based testing model also. The way this works - buying and testing across many devices is a costly and a time consuming process. These automation tools - have a remote cloud system, which you can leverage for a fee. They will have almost all the devices that are there in the globally accepted markets. Once you have written your automation test codes, you can run them on any device from their cloud system.

So to test across so many devices, its NOT possible manually - you have to use an automation tool. The automation tools today are building this kind of a framework to capture the QA market.

This is the best way to test an App across a wide variety of phones (like in Android).

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

This may help http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html.

If you're on Windows you will need to install the USB driver. Then, on your Devices tab (Window->Show View->Other->Android->Devices) you should see a new row appear when you connect your device to your workstation with a USB cable (although LG handsets are problematic in my experience).